# Extract from XML and load to Postgres using sqlalchemy - bottleneck

Tags: python, sqlite, postgresql, amazon-web-services, sqlalchemy

I need to load a lot of XML data into a postgres database (in excess of 10M rows per day). Everything happens very fast locally when I use sqlite. Things slow down when I use postgres locally, and things really slow down when I use AWS EC2/RDS. Below is some pseudocode and benchmarks. Any clue what is causing the bottleneck?

```
1 for observation in xml_data:
2   new_reading = Reading()
3   for attr_name, attr_value in observation.iteritems():
4     setattr(new_reading, attr_name, attr_val)
5   session.add(new_reading)
6 session.commit()
```

I am using Python 2.7.5, postgres 9.2.4, SQLAlchemy==0.9.6, psycopg2==2.5.3

- Local, sqlite

  - lines 1-5: 13k readings/second
  - line 6: 9.8k rows/second
- Local, postgres

  - lines 1-5: 13k readings/second
  - line 6: 5.7k rows/second
- AWS, RDS w/ postgres

  - lines 1-5: 5.1k readings/second
  - line 6: 1.1k rows/second

I am confused as to why I am seeing a reduction in write speed from sqlite to postgres, and even more confused as to why my 11" MBA is faster than an AWS m1.medium instance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ORM are typically not designed to do bulk insert. But seems that SQLAlchemy tries to give you something: http://sqlalchemy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/faq/performance.html#i-m-inserting-400-000-rows-with-the-orm-and-it-s-really-slow

There is some specialized ways to insert a whole bunch of lines:

- Ask your DB to [read a file](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-copy.html)
- [Insert statement](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.2/static/sql-insert.html) with multiple rows (You may insert them 1000 by 1000 for example).
- [Prepared statements](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/sql-prepare.html) (send and parse INSERT once, send data multiple times)

I personally use insert with multiple rows more often than other solutions.

The differences you see between your localhost test and AWS test may be the time spent in round trips between your program and the postgresql server, so reducing the number of round trips (bulk insert) may be the solution.